# Jssor Slider display issue with chrome 64 bits

Tags: google-chrome, jssor

I have implemented one of the Jssor slider 
However it's not working properly with Chrome 64bit
The site is the following www.mariabarriga.com.br
There is a display issue in the main display and also in other slider such as 
http://mariabarriga.com.br/lookbook/vestido-gestante/9
Does anybody know how to fix it
Best 
Renato

Comment: Hi, I have exactly the same issue. Let me know when you get it fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Update to the latest 19.0 version & it works. Even if you have 19.0 already. Redownload the latest from jssor.com & update jssor.js & jssor.slider.js files. I did that & it works for me.

Comment: Thanks It works !!! I updated the files and now it's working properly. Thanks for your help and support

Comment: @Renato Hi, Can you please tick as Answer. so the others get benefited as well :)